# CSS attribute selector matching void value

Tags: css

Is it possible to match elements with attribute with no value?

I.e.: match this: `<element attribute>`.

Do **not** match this: `<element attribute="">`. `<element attribute=" ">`, `<element attribute="<any Unicode string>">`.

(Without using `[attribute]:not([attribute^="a"i]):not([attribute^="b"i]):not([attribute^="<all remaining Unicode characters">)`.)

Comment: Probably not possible since DOM isn't interpreted as a string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this with CSS, as `<element attribute>` is the same as `<element attribute="">`.

You can read this here in the spec: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2

> Empty attribute syntax:
> Just the attribute name. The value is implicitly the empty string.

Comment: Well this is excellent pointer since my use-case actually was to match either void or empty string values, and I didn't realise both are the same thing from CSS perspective. (Haven't even tried to test before asking.)
So thanks, now I know that `[attribute=""]` should  match both `<element attribute>` AND `<element attribute="">`.